# Put inline certificate in YAML

Tags: yaml

I've a certificate that I need to copy in a YAML property. Something that could look like this:

```
ca_cert: | -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I've tried the YAML validator but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 19):

A block scalar cannot start at the same line as the indicator `|`. Also, you need to indent the block scalar:

```
ca_cert: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIDBzCCAe+gAwIBAgIJALOT/fiqj4yhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMBoxGDAWBgNV
    BAMMD3d3dy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTAeFw0xNzA1MDMxNDA2NDVaFw0yNzA1MDExNDA2
    NDVaMBoxGDAWBgNVBAMMD3d3dy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
    BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALHEIGNhuQsD1MI3zE5Kts5zN91ggbFjFq0aLWjYuIB6
    ttfpS158b9x9oWbdACAqGIHC5i1/iwiJkW8J1UcxtPOOHZy4s9E48KnPzJOd6yAv
    pxsBuns78Jx5hgBBt+J2TSwEL+Hi40HhBiog+Omk2pi3juMGkhFJaaSiBQf7gA0E
    TXSC5iLK1XPCd6aQpDZwxQpjDNeDk9CR6asqtPJcm9X2skLuNWyIr8dKHpdzoQ5A
    /5GhmtLC/WYwZdqi14Gwph+GS7a2eQYzbGwIZWfcPiMytoNGidDC2HurRpGt91PK
    PxfXDhDk8taBuboHFDAW7beR/x68pPm+p2mTtVt+cS0CAwEAAaNQME4wHQYDVR0O
    BBYEFDpuS3ujMg9wC09nBy/QRQI8PipqMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFDpuS3ujMg9wC09n
    By/QRQI8PipqMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAFh6UUfa
    YL9iLREMGgHTvn4O4nMtsWEEW46/9o4ZcGgVgIL343qD1G0isaTLStKHB5C653N0
    40DU/n9Fcver/x5EhKzjp9QcOSNizFDUG88tCOuW3H+EsTHsCwxdVvENzBT1+Z3N
    JkT8oHVjEc3LBeQmVZLHiWWA9CSVW9b6qco0OjLwLe92f1EWKjqrHPW+5xM3zC0e
    T2h5p4ApY74Pyl892HJrb/dd2DjzYDnXuvcDFZTAr9o5YgcS1jx0Gt9jE1FM7rhk
    GF5aek4Bir9K8xwNBTc8R+dvl2OhQYoxIglSApkNI+n0J9/1pfPnpwojBHifqy/p
    G9oErrv2EQ642e4=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```